# Directly Navigating a Browser with an XBAP

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xbap

I'm working on a *full-trust* WPF browser application (XBAP) and have come across a snag.  An application on the client is wired to handle navigation requests with a certain prefix/protocol. (For example, 'foo://...") Additionally, the application handles these differently depending on which browser creates the request.  I've tried the Page's 'NavigationService.Navigate()' method, but for some strange reason this involves WebRequest objects, which raises a NotSupportedException saying "The URI prefix is not recognized."  I can create a WebBrowser control and successfully navigate IT with this prefix, but the application recognizes it as a different browser and reacts differently.  If I were using Silverlight, I'd be to directly set the browser's 'window.location' which works perfectly.  But of course, this is only appears to be available in the Silverlight framework.

*So bottom line, what I need to do is trigger the browser hosting the XBAP to navigate to a URI with this special prefix.*

Whew.  That's all, I think.  Thanks.

**Update**: The .Net Framework 4.0 will allow direct access to the browser's DOM which will solve this problem, however I am still scrounging for ways of accomplishing this in .Net 3.x.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use BrowserInteropHelper.ClientSite to access the DOM. Check out this post for a sample:

http://blogs.msdn.com/changov/archive/2009/03/01/scripting-out-of-an-xbap.aspx

Note that this would only work for Internet Explorer though.